# How programmatically deselect row identified by id in jquery DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I generate a DataTable thanks the plug-in dataTables and I assign a id to each row

```
  table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": source_dataTable,
    "columns": columns,
    "columnDefs": defs,

    'fnCreatedRow': function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        $(nRow).attr('id', aData[0]);//assign an id
    },
    "language": {
        "url": dataTabe_text_source
    }
});
```

I want to  now programically deselect (and why not select)  rows IDENTIFIED  FROM THEIR ID

I want to do it from id in something like that

```
table.Deselect(id);
```

If you have the tip , could you help me please?

Comment: var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var row = table.row('#row-42');

this way you can make the logic of new function.

Comment: and there removeClass or addClass ('selected')

Comment: it is a good idea but unfortunately, var row = table.row('#row-42'); return an object on which you canot do removeClass()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked for correct syntax at http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html and found that my example should be like:

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 table.$('tr#row-42').removeClass('selected');
```

This reference is giving correct type of object where addClass and removeClass would apply.

Comment: Nice to suggest great helps = table.$('tr#'+id).removeClass('selected');